# Переполняется стек. c#. Задание с событиями(event) Ping pong

Tags: c#, события, стек, переполнение

Есть два класса, у каждого свой метод для вывода информации, в обеих вызывается метод который связан на метод другого класса.

Вопрос в том, как убрать переполнение стека.

Задание 6.20    Лабораторная работа. Делегаты

Задания

1. Напишите "пинг-понг":

•   2 класса Ping и Pong

•   один уведомляет другого, о том, что "произошёл пинг", другой - о том, что "произошёл понг",

•   одна пара объектов "играют" между собой, другая пара - между собой и т.д.

и выводить на консоль соответсвующие сообщения, что-то вроди такого:

1. Ping received Pong.
2. Pong received Ping.
3. Ping received Pong.
4. Pong received Ping.
5. Ping received Pong.

   ```
   class Program
   {
       class Pong
       {
           public delegate void Ud();
           public event Ud Vivod;
           public void Udar()
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Понг отбил пинг");
               if (Vivod != null)
                   Vivod();
           }
       }

       class Ping
       {
           public delegate void Ud();
           public event Ud Vivod;
           public void Udar()
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Пинг отбил понг");
               if (Vivod != null) 
               Vivod();
           }
       }
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Ping ping = new Ping();
           Pong pong = new Pong();
           Ping.Ud v = pong.Udar;
           Pong.Ud vi = ping.Udar;

           ping.Vivod += v;
           pong.Vivod += vi;
           ping.Udar();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Вы же сами это зациклили: `Ping.Ud v = pong.Udar; Pong.Ud vi = ping.Udar;`.

Comment: ну, правильно. Не правильно то, что вызывается событие в методе, а потом в этом событии другой метод....

Comment: хм, это Вы мне объясняете? Скажите лучше, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Добавил задание. Ну... наверное что-бы стек не переполнялся. Что-бы эти два метода вызывались очееень долго

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то такое получилось

```
class PingPong
{
    private readonly string _nameMe;
    private readonly string _nameOpponent;

    public PingPong(string nameMe, string nameOpponent)
    {
        _nameMe = nameMe;
        _nameOpponent = nameOpponent;

    }

    public delegate void KnockHandler();
    public event KnockHandler Knock;

    public void KnockHandlerInstance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{_nameMe} received {_nameOpponent}");
    }

    public void RaiseKnock()
    {
        Knock?.Invoke();
    }
}

class PingPongFactory
{
    private void RunPingPong(PingPong ping, PingPong pong)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ping.RaiseKnock();

            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();

            pong.RaiseKnock();

            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();

        }
    }

    public Task LaunchPair(int id)
    {
        var pingName = $"Ping{id}";
        var pongName = $"Pong{id}";

        PingPong ping = new PingPong(pingName, pongName);
        PingPong pong = new PingPong(pongName, pingName);
        ping.Knock += pong.KnockHandlerInstance;
        pong.Knock += ping.KnockHandlerInstance;

        Task result = new Task(() => RunPingPong(ping, pong));

        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==ConsoleAppPingPong==");
        Console.WriteLine("Для начала нажмите Ввод");
        Console.ReadLine();

        PingPongFactory factory = new PingPongFactory();

        Task task1 = factory.LaunchPair(1);
        task1.Start();
        Task task2 = factory.LaunchPair(2);
        task2.Start();

        task1.Wait();
        task2.Wait();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное, нужна пауза и после Pong?

Comment: @VladD, да, пожалуй, верное замечание.